# Can I use JSON-LD for Products while using MICRODATA for Reviews?

Tags: rich-snippets, microdata, structured-data, json-ld

The Reviews are included as dynamic data in an iframe so we do not have access to the main page to add the JSON-LD. If that doesn't work, I'd appreciate suggestions for an alternate approach.

Comment: Google does not currently link data between json-ld and microdata. I also suspect it would not connect or include any data in an iframe. Try running a page in the rich results testing tool to see what it sees.